# How to Update Shopware to Version 6.5 Using Dockware Container

Tags: shopware, shopware6, mysqlupgrade

I have already installed Shopware 6.4 using Dockware through the `docker-compose.yml` file. Now, I'm aiming to upgrade Shopware to version 6.5. However, I've encountered a challenge: Shopware 6.4 uses MySQL 5.7, while Shopware 6.5 requires MySQL 8.

In my situation, I have a database dump file, and I've set up a new Dockware container with Shopware 6.5 and MySQL 8. I imported the dump file into the MySQL 8 database. Unfortunately, this approach isn't working as expected, and I'm encountering various PHP errors. It appears that the issue might be related to database schema migration, but I'm uncertain. Additionally, I'm not confident whether I'm following the correct process to update Shopware.

Could someone provide a step-by-step explanation of the update process? I would greatly appreciate any guidance to help me navigate this situation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After you imported the dump from your 6.4 installation, you have to execute the migrations again. Shell into your app servers container and run this CLI command:

```
bin/console database:migrate --all
```

You should also re-index the data afterwards:

```
bin/console dal:refresh:index
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance! I followed your suggestions, and the PHP errors have been resolved. However, I'm currently facing an issue with images not loading properly. I suspect this might be due to changes in image paths or caching problems after the update.